# Import JSON code into Javascript file with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I have generated some JSON code with the NuGet Packet Newtonsoft `JsonConvert`. But what I want is now to import that code into a javascript file so I can create a google map.

My Json code looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": 'Alibaug',
        "lat": '18.641400',
        "lng": '72.872200',
        "description": 'Alibaug is a coastal town and a municipal council in Raigad District in the Konkan region of Maharashtra, India.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Mumbai',
        "lat": '18.964700',
        "lng": '72.825800',
        "description": 'Mumbai formerly Bombay, is the capital city of the Indian state of Maharashtra.'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Pune',
        "lat": '18.523600',
        "lng": '73.847800',
        "description": 'Pune is the seventh largest metropolis in India, the second largest in the state of Maharashtra after Mumbai.'
    }
];
```

The language I use is C# in an asp.net form project.

Have also a look on my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480598/make-routes-on-google-map-in-asp-net-website

Any Ideas for solve my problem? 
Thanks

Comment: your json is a valid javascript object. `var arr=[.....]; alert(arr[0].title);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, either make an ajax request or use the <% %> notation on your .aspx page. The second is easier :)

Example:

I have a method getMapJson() that returns my Json inside the codebehind of MyWebPage.aspx page. It's important that you make it static or else you won't be able to call it from MyWebPage.aspx

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class MyWebPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public static string getMapJson()
        {
             //your code
             return json;
        }
    }
}
```

In the MyWebPage.aspx page, in a script, do something like this:

```
var myJsonVariable = $.parseJSON('<%=MyApplication.MyWebPage.getMapJson()%>');
```

And now you have your Json, already deserialized, in your myJsonVariable :)

You could also import a static propriety instead of a method, but you will have to set its value no later than Page_Load, because the stuff inside <% %> is calculated only once per page load, so it won't change unless you reload.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC you can do this:

```
public Coordinates
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Lat { get; set; }
    public string Lng { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult GetCoordinates(){

    // get your coordinates
    List<Coordinates> coordinates = GetCoordinatesFromDatabase();

    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var objectAsJsonString = serializer.Serialize(coordinates );

    return Json(objectAsJsonString);
}
```

And then in your javascript you need just to deserialize the json:

```
var coordinates = null;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
        coordinates = JSON.parse(result);
        // operate with your object
    }
});
```

I hope this is of help to you.

Comment: No, I don't use MVC, it's an asp form project

Answer (score 0):

Make an ajax request to your asp page, rendering the JSON.

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/